# Access bosh-lite from remote machine

Tags: cloud-foundry, iptables, cf-bosh

I install a bosh-lite on my physical machine1, and then I want to use boshcli to access the bosh director on another machine2. machine2 and machine1 can connected.
I tried to use iptables snat ,but not work. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can first connect from the same local machine using the CLI. If that works, make sure you can then connect to the machine1 IP from machine2 (not bosh-lite, but host).  If that works you need to add the route on machine 2 to tell it to send traffic for bosh-lite vm IPs to machine 1 ips.

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.100.0/24 192.168.50.4
```

where the first range is network range defined in bosh manifest, and 2nd argument is the gateway, likely machine 1 IP.